# Assign by reference a list of results to a number of columns of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Imagine you have 2 distributions resulting from two simulations stored in a `data.frame`:

```
sim1 = 1:10
sim2 = 91:100
sim = data.frame(sim1, sim2)
```

Now, we want to find the 10% and 90% percentiles of each distribution. This can be done by:

```
diffSim = ncol(sim)
confidenceInterval = c(0.1, 0.9)
results = lapply(1:diffSim, function(j) {quantile(sim[, j], confidenceInterval, 
                                   names = FALSE, type = 3)})
```

I would like to store these results in a `data.table` by assigning by reference (`:=`). However, I first need to get`results` in the appropriate shape (i.e. a data.table of 1 row and 4 columns). To do so, I subsequently apply `unlist`, `matrix` and `as.data.table` to `results`:

```
DT = data.table(Col1 = "Result")

DT[, c("col2", "col3", "col4", "col5") := as.data.table(matrix(unlist(results), nrow = 1))]
```

I don't like this at all. Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: why "1 row 4 columns"?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, because `DT` consists also of other rows

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily shorter, but everything in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sim)[, .(col1 = 'Result',
               cols = paste0('col',2:5),
               vals = unlist(lapply(.SD, quantile, probs = confidenceInterval, type = 3)))
           ][, dcast(.SD, col1 ~ cols, value.var = 'vals')]
```

which gives:

> ```
>      col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
> 1: Result    1    9   91   99
> ```